# WPF Textbox Not Reacting to Validation Error

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF app with a UserControl that contains a Grid which in turn contains several TextBoxes:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
               Text="Application ID" />

    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
             Text="{Binding AzureAppID}"/>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
               Text="Vault URL" />

    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
             Text="{Binding AzureVaultUrl}" />

</Grid>
```

I've implemented validation using the INotifyDataErrorInfo interface, which is working and correctly flags errors (e.g., AzureAppID, bound to the first TextBox, is not allowed to be empty).

In fact, if I enter an invalid value in either TextBox, the grid control which contains them lights up with a red border, signifying an error. But neither TextBox gets highlighted to indicate the error.

Why do other controls -- including other TextBoxes embedded within, say, a DataGrid -- react properly, but these ones inside a grid do not?

This is in a project built under Net 4.7.

**Chalk This Up To Stupidity**

It turns out my validation routine was tagging errors, in the case of the fields in question, with slightly different names from the properties the errors were associated with. Naturally, the WPF engine couldn't match up the error to the textboxes based on what the textboxes were bound to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think simple answer is that data grid is designed to listen notification ( say empty not allwoed would be notifified back with appropriate message via eventargs..ofcourse INotifyErrorInfo interface provides that infra behind-the-scene)

When considering plain grid/custom control as you say, you need to take care of that.

Comment: Thanx, @Rahul. It sounds like I need to add code to set validation errors on the textbox...which seems like an odd thing to have to do. I've been playing with doing that in a custom Grid control, but so far without success.

Comment: I've tagged this as the answer, even though it wasn't, because it suggested some things that eventually led me to the right answer. See the edited question for more information.